# C# - Obtaining Digital Certificates from VeriSign and Verifying Authenticity

Tags: c#, certificate, digital-certificate, verisign

Does VeriSign allow developers to obtain "sandbox" digital certificates which can be used in development, much like PayPal allows developers to set up sandbox accounts?

Furthermore, does anyone have an implementation in C# about how a client can send the certificate to a server, and the server checks with VeriSign that the digital certificate is valid?

Comment: I believe the client-cert to server-cert mapping needs to happen at the IIS level. Although there is a way to specify cert needs in the web.config file for WCF style of communications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check with verisign, you use [normal certificate validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702579.aspx) (as you would with any other certificate).

A "sandbox" certificate is [a self-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate). You trust yourself ([add your own certificate to the trusted root store](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)) and so the certificate you signed yourself is trusted too.

Comment: you can use free softwares to create these self-signed certs. 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I need to simulate a system preferrably using VeriSign though.  So VeriSign does not offer a free service for developers so that they can test their applications before deployment?

Comment: They don't, as there isn't an easy way to create a sandbox certificate because that certificate can easily be abused, e.g. to do a MITM. Furthermore, it doesn't matter that Verisign is your CA. In fact it is very unwise to code specifically against VeriSign because that means you can never switch CA's

Comment: @dtech Thank you for your response dtech :)  I appreciate it immensely :)